# How to use inbuild shell command with popen

Tags: c, shell, gcc, popen, fgets

So, I have to build a custom shell, which can execute all sh commands and all binaries located in /usr/bin and others binairies files included into shell, but I currently cannot use inbuild cd and doesn't know how to make it work even through chdir (i tried multiples times, but if chdir is inside the loop, it'll recreate a fork for each shell).

If you could help me as I'm a student and give me tips and advices, that'd be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "color.h"

int expertShell()
{       
    while(1)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char path[1035], command[1024];
        printf(ANSI_COLOR_BLUE "☁  " ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
        fgets(command, sizeof(command)-1, stdin);

        if(strncmp(command, "cd", 2) == 0)
        {
            chdir(strtok(command, "cd "));
        }

        if(strncmp(command, "exit", 4) == 0)
        {
            exit(1);
        }

        if(strncmp(command, "ls", 2) == 0)
        {
            strcat(strtok(command,"\n"), " --color=always");
        }

        if(strncmp(command, "nano", 4) == 0 || strncmp(command, "vi", 2) == 0)
        {
            system(command);
        }
        else
        {
            fp = popen(command, "r");

            if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to run command\n" );
                exit(1);
            }

            while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
                printf("%s", path);
            }

            pclose(fp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you add absolute path as prefix in `command` and pass to `popen()` call. `#include <unistd.h>` is also missing in your file.

Comment: absolute path isn't needed as prefix, the problem, actually, is that the shell doesn't change the directory as popen is creating another fork, for the unistd.h it's fixed

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `popen()` forking a child. The child process will spawn in the `cwd` of the parent. The issue is with `chdir()` failing to change to an inexistent directory. The root cause of getting an incorrect directory is in `fgets()`. The variable `command` is terminated with `\n`. If you add just after `fgets()` this line `command[strlen(command)-1]=0;` it will replace `\n` with `\0`. Then `chdir()` will work and `popen()` will run in the correct directory.

Comment: @alvits oh completely forgot that chdir couldn't open while there were a \n and no end of line identifier, thanks mate ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(cdInBuild != 0)
```

You need to actually call the function. As written, this is checking if `cdInBuild` is a non-null function pointer (which is always true).

```
if(cdInBuild(command) != 0)
```

Comment: It was a typo on the code, which doesn't change the behavior of the shell, the true problem is still there.